# Url decoding problem on deployment with IIS and FastCGI on windows server

Tags: django, angular, iis, urlencode, fastcgi

I realized an app front Angular, back-end Django, deployed on Windows server using IIS and FastCGI.
This app serves media files on a certain URL. It works fine locally on dev server.
I can access all my files correctly on path "medias/myfilepath".

The problem is in production on IIS. Special characters are encoded in a different way. I think it is FastCGI that does it. I cannot find the encoding rules, and my Django app is not able to decode properly so my requests end up with a 404 error.

Here are some examples of the difference of encoding between local server and production server :

- **à** | local : %C3%80 | prod : %25C0
- **ù** | local : %C3%99 | prod : %25D9
- **É** | local : %C3%89 | prod : %25C9

I can't find any documentation on the subject, I don't have access to configurations on CGI side. I could update decoding on Django side to fit it, but I can't find which one applies ...

Someone would have some ideas on that subject ?

Comment: Are you looking for documentation on encoding differences?

Comment: If you have some documentation that can explain which encoding method is used in each case, I would be glad to read it !! :)

Comment: There is very little documentation on this topic, I think it's necessary for you to post the detailed error message.

Answer (score 0):

this happens because your local machine is set to windows-12xx charset instead of UTF-8. I found it most comfortable to use urllib in python to convert the fastcgi url encoding to the desired string.

for example if I'm trying to respond with a Test whose name starts with text appended to the URL (my prod machine charset is windows-1255):

```
#views.py

import urllib.parse

def searchViewText(request,text): #text received in windows-1255 encoding
    text = urllib.parse.unquote(text,'windows-1255') #

    tests = Test.objects.filter(name__icontains = text)

context={

    
        "tests" : tests,
      
    }
    return render(request,"search.html",context)
```